# Error converting data type nvarchar to float - nvarchar to float to int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't have that much experience with writing SQL queries and I have hit upon a problem. I have read in a table of data into a temporary table (#Temp_Results) and need to change the format of various columns before moving the data to the end table. 
What Im trying to do below is take a column (Oil2) that is an nvarchar and convert it to a tinyint and put the result into a new column (Oil4) then drop Oil2 - I realise I will loose decimal places but thats not a problem. The CASE statement is designed to capture anything that is not a number, seeing as the original datatype is nvarchar there could be anything in there and I'm only interested in the numbers.

However when I run the code I get 'Error converting data type nvarchar to float' pointing towards the 'UPDATE' line of code and I cant figure out how to get round it.

Can any of you guys spot my rookie mistake?

```
ALTER TABLE tempdb..#Temp_Results       /*Add new column with datatype of tinyint*/ 
ADD Oil4 tinyint
GO

UPDATE tempdb..#Temp_Results            
SET tempdb..#Temp_Results.Oil4 = CASE 
WHEN ISNUMERIC(tempdb..#Temp_Results.Oil2)=1
THEN CAST(ROUND(CAST(tempdb..#Temp_H_Results.Oil2 as float), 0) AS tinyint)
ELSE NULL
END

ALTER TABLE tempdb..#Temp_H_Results     /*Drop redundant column of data in wrong (nvarchar) format*/
DROP COLUMN Oil2
Go
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to Decimal in stead of float

```
CONVERT(varchar(28), cast(tempdb..#Temp_H_Results.Oil2 as decimal(28,0)))
```